# powerBI Dax - two unrelated tables/dates comparison/if overlap, sum variable in one table

Tags: date, powerbi, compare

I would like to create a measure total_count from two unrelated tables (Table 1 & Table 2)-

Table 1

| start date | end date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22/05/2020 | 31/07/2020 | 3 |
| 25/06/2021 | 08/12/2021 | 4 |
| 17/01/2022 | 10/08/2022 | 6 |
| 15/05/2020 | 11/10/2022 | 10 |

Table 2

| program date |
| --- |
| 01/06/2020 |
| 31/07/2021 |
| 27/03/2022 |

RESULT -

| program date | total_count |
| --- | --- |
| 01/06/2020 | 13 |
| 31/07/2021 | 14 |
| 27/03/2022 | 16 |

criteria - if the program date in Table 2 falls in between a period in Table 1, sum up the "count" from Table 1.

I have attempted to create a measure (total_count) in Table 2

```
total_count = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(Table 1[count]), 
    DATESBETWEEN('Table 2'[program date], (Table 1[start date]), (Table 1[end date]))
           )
```

Can I get help to properly creating a correct measure? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
total_count = 
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
        FILTER('filename',
         Table1[end date]>=MAX(Table2[program date]) && Table1[start date] <= MAX(Table2[program date])
         ),
    Table1[count])
)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?